# JTable Render And Editor Query?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In the JTable editor mode I have JTextField, when a value is entered and the focus is lost from the editor,the value is displayed as text in the render mode.

The Scenario is this :: If a wrong is value is entered in the text field, how can I restore the focus back in the editor and in the text field without allowing the focus to travel to render..

Thank You in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override the cellEditor's stopCellEditing and run a validation in there: if valid return super, if not return false